Please correct helpful flag tooltip in impact box
When hovering over "NN helpful flags" in the Impact box on the Activity page, the following tooltip text appears:

Total number of raised flags marked useful

Flags are marked "helpful" and not "useful", so perhaps this tooltip could be updated or corrected for consistency.

